# Is it possible to simultaneously run two while loops in R?

Tags: r, while-loop, functional-programming

I have two functions that use while loops and want to combine them so that both loops run simultaneously. The first function/loop enables the user to interactively input data into the console using the numerical keys 1 to 5, while the second function/loop displays a countdown timer to inform the user how long the experiment has remaining. I want to be able to start the experiment and the countdown simultaneously.

I have already tried, unsuccessfully, to combine the two functions into one function:

```
record_data = function(x) {
require(tictoc) #load required package
require(tcltk)

time_period = readline("Length of observation period (mins): ") # requires user input
  time_period = as.numeric(time_period)

  pb <- tkProgressBar("Timer")
  start = Sys.time()

while(T){       #open infinite while loop
    tic()       #start timer
    elapsed = as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(), start, units = 'mins'))
    remaining = time_period - elapsed
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    setTkProgressBar(pb,
                     remaining / time_period,
                     label = sprintf("Time remaining: %i min", round(remaining)))
    if (remaining <= 0)
      break

    input_state=readline("State input: ")  #allow for entry of state
    if(input_state %in% 1:5){    #check if it's acceptable 
        elapsed=toc()            #if it is then end timer and record data
        write.table(cbind(input_state,elapsed$toc-elapsed$tic),'results.txt',col.names=F,row.names=F,quote=F,append=T)
    }else if(input_state=='t'){  #if input is 't' 
        break                    #break out of while loop
    }else if(input_state <1 | input_state > 5 & input_state!='t'){#if input is not and accepted state AND is not 't'
     print('thats not an allowed state- please try another')
     } 
  }
  Sys.sleep(2)
  close(pb)

}
```

Function one (collecting data with user input in the console):

```
record_data = function(x) {
require(tictoc) #load required package
while(T){       #open infinite while loop
    tic()       #start timer
    input_state=readline("State input: ")  #allow for entry of state
    if(input_state %in% 1:5){    #check if it's acceptable 
        elapsed=toc()            #if it is then end timer and record data
        write.table(cbind(input_state,elapsed$toc-elapsed$tic),'results.txt',col.names=F,row.names=F,quote=F,append=T)
    }else if(input_state=='t'){  #if input is 't' 
        break                    #break out of while loop
    }else if(input_state <1 | input_state > 5 & input_state!='t'){#if input is not and accepted state AND is not 't'
     print('thats not an allowed state- please try another')
     } 
  }
}
```

Function two (a timer to countdown the experiment):

```
timer = function(x) {
  require(tcltk)
  time_period = readline("Length of observation period (mins): ")
  time_period = as.numeric(time_period)

  pb <- tkProgressBar("Timer")
  start = Sys.time()
  while (TRUE) {
    elapsed = as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(), start, units = 'mins'))
    remaining = time_period - elapsed
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    setTkProgressBar(pb,
                     remaining / time_period,
                     label = sprintf("Time remaining: %i min", round(remaining)))
    if (remaining <= 0)
      break
  }
  Sys.sleep(2)
  close(pb)
```

My attempt clearly doesn't work and I am not sure how to troubleshoot the problem. I want the function to deploy a timer that begins automatically when collecting data. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some simplified proof-of-concept functions, that don't rely on `tkltk` etc. I haven't studied the code in detail, but I doubt all of that complexity is required to put your point across.

Comment: Function one doesn't rely on `tcltk` and works well. Unfortunately I haven't been able to write a simple countdown function that doesn't use `tcltk`.